# VSCode 上のターミナルから export コマンドを実行するとエラーになる

Tags: windows, vscode

VSCodeをWindows 11のPCに入れてターミナルでexportを使おうと思ったら以下のメッセージが表示されました。

```
export : 用語 'export' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。
名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
```

Macでいつも作業をしていたので、結構とまどい、自身で調べてみてもいまいち回答が見つからなく質問した次第です。

Macのときはこんなことなかった(はず)・・・
HOW TO ご存じの方、お知恵をお借りできませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` は主に Linux (Unix) 系の OS で使われるコマンドであり、Windows には存在しません。(VSCode も直接は関係ありません)

恐らく環境変数を設定する目的であれば、`set` を代わりに使用して下さい。

参考:
[［set / export］環境変数を設定](https://xtech.nikkei.com/it/atcl/column/15/042000103/080700061/)